# How do I print the following pattern using nested loops in python?

Tags: python, function, loops, pycharm, range

I'm a beginner in python and I've been trying to print this for the past 40 minutes. Any help on how I can do this would be greatly appreciated.
[The first line has 11 spaces, the second has 7 spaces, the third has 3 spaces, and the last has no spaces.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkCr0.png)

```
for row in range(4):
for column in range(row + 1):
    print(column, end='')
print("")
```

So far I have two loops. This one prints: [(image)](https://i.)
The other one is: `n = 3 k = 3 for i in range(0,n+1): for j in range(k-i, -1, -1): print(j, end='') print()`

That prints:

[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h51FR.png) stack.imgur.com/IAIHk.png

I'm stuck on what to do, but I think I have a general idea. Please help!

Comment: Please let me know if my solution was usefull because I spent time trying to help you and, so I hope that was what you were looking for. If so, you should mark my solution as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you use a monospaced font

```py
for i in range(1, 5):
    j = 0
    spaces = 2 * (4 - i) - 1

    while j < i:
        print(j, end = "")
        j += 1

    if spaces == -1:
        j -= 1
    else:
        print(" " * spaces, end = "")

    while j > 0:
        j -= 1
        print(j, end = "")
    print()
```

If you want this work for any number you can define a function like

```py
def f(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        j = 0
        spaces = 2 * (n - i) - 1

        while j < i:
            print(j, end = "")
            j += 1

        if spaces == -1:
            j -= 1
        else:
            print(" " * spaces, end = "")

        while j > 0:
            j -= 1
            print(j, end = "")
        print()
```

For example, f(6) will print

```
0         0
01       10
012     210
0123   3210
01234 43210
01234543210
```

Hope I helped